# how to create table alert view

Tags: iphone, xcode, uialertview

hi iam new to iphone development,first time i am using alert view ..
in my application when my button pressed it has to open up table view in alert view and when user selects one of these it has to update to button text after alert view hide....

any idea like how to do this one ,i am right now using picker view for selecting this professsion from list of professions...

Comment: Are you going for the same idea as the "Select a Wi-Fi Network" alert?

Answer (score 1):

[Heres a solution](http://starterstep.wordpress.com/2009/03/24/custom-uialertview-with-uitableview/)

I've used it before and it worked ok. Ended up changing it to a grouped style tableview with a clear background that appeared over the view.